# android authorizing with facebook

Tags: android, facebook

i'm trying to authorize my mobile app with facebook, but when facebook authorization window is closed, it doesn't come back to my application's continueLoading(1) method..
can't understand why:

```
private void authorizeFacebook(final Loader loader) {       
    String[] permissions = new String[] {"friends_status", "user_status"};
    facebook.authorize(this, permissions , new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            Log.e("finish", "oncomplete");
            //SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
            //editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
            //editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
            //editor.commit();                
            loader.continueLoading(1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) { 
            Log.i("FacebookAuthorize", error.toString());               
            app.alert("Facebook Connection Error", "Please try to re-open the application", "Ok", loader);      
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) { 
            Log.i("FacebookAuthorize", e.toString());               
            app.alert("Facebook Connection Error", "Please try to re-open the application", "Ok", loader);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.i("FacebookAuthorize", "onCancel");
            app.alert("Facebook Connection Error", "Please try to re-open the application", "Ok", loader);
        }
    });

}

    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

the first step of the loader:

```
   private void continueLoading(int step) {     
    switch(step)
    {
            //loading current user facebook profile
    case 1: progressBar.incrementProgressBy(750);               
            loadingStatus.setText("Getting user's facebook details");                               
            facebookRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);         
            facebookConnection = new FacebookConnection(this, 1);
            facebookRunner.request("me",facebookConnection);   
            app.setFacebook(facebook);
            app.setFacebookRunner(facebookRunner);
            break;
```

instead of coming back to my app, it just close everything..

Comment: What this Line will do? loader.continueLoading(1);

Comment: it continue loading... i'll add it to my question

Comment: After login succeeds if you need to move to new Activity say Activity_1 , then add this lines startActivity(new Intent(this,Activity_1.class));

Comment: but everything is happening in the same activity.. i want it to continue in the same activity

Comment: Do one thing Just print one Log Message before continueLoading() . And also remove all switch cases inside continueLoading() method.And Print one more Log Message inside continueLoading().. Do it for testing and see ur method is calling or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The facebook android sdk has two different authentication flows:

1) SSO - will be used if the user has installed the facebook app on the same device.
If this is the case then the facebook sdk you are using will start a new intent to the facebook app to authenticate the user against your app.
To be able to know when that's done you'll need to add this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

2) If the device does not have the facebook app installed then the SDK will open it's own dialog for user authentication, in this case the `DialogListener` implementation you pass to  the `authorize` method will be used.

You need to have both (`DialogListener` and `onActivityResult`) to handle both cases.

Comment: ohh so you're saying that i should use the continueLoading method inside the dialog listener for users without facebook app and the onActivityResult for the users who does have.
so if i understand this correctly i should add the continueLoading(1) inside the onActivityResult aswell ?

Comment: No. You only call `facebook.authorize` then the sdk decides if to use its' dialog or use an intent. If an intent was used then the `onActivityResult` method is executed, which then informs the sdk (`facebook.authorizeCallback`) and the sdk should then call the `onComplete` of the `DialogListener` implementation you supplied. All you need to do is add the `onActivityResult` method.

Comment: but i have an onActivityResult method.. i always had.. i've even paste it inside my code snippet

Comment: oh. sorry. I missed that... put logging in the two methods to see if it gets to either one

Comment: it get inside the authorize and the than the onActivityResults but then nothing...

Comment: If it gets to the `onActivityResults` it's a good sign. Why it stops there is a good question. Is the code you posted your entire code? Maybe there are other things in your code that can shed some light on the problem?

Comment: the class is very long, but this is the parts being used.. i've tried to put the facebook.authorize() out side of a method, and now it doesn't log the onActivityResults.. i'm really confused

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11883/discussion-between-nitzan-tomer-and-asaf-nevo)

Comment: Click the "continue this discussion in chat", better talk here.

Comment: ok, i couldn't really find what my problem was, but i did as you suggested and i've rearranged my loader class to be short and simple.
and now it works, god knows why :) thanks for the help and the tips